# How to use GCP Translation API to process a table in BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, translation

I have a table in my BigQuery like the following

```
article_title author
いい天気です    Inoue
富士山絶景      Kojiro
...           ...
```

The article title column is some Japanese articles. I'd like to use GCP Translation API to translate the article_title column into English and convert the table into the following

```
article_title_en author
Good weather     Inoue
Mt. Fuji view    Kojiro
...
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Check out this demo from Cloud Next '19 - [Viant’s Journey:The Non-Engineer Guide to BigQuery](https://youtu.be/BpgW27YLSS8?t=1461) - it shows similar use case but with use of Vision API. This is done with Magnus - part of Potens.io BigQuery Tools - it is available on [GCP Marketplace](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/potens-io/potensio) for you to try. Obviously, I highly recommend to see whole video! You can see also all documentation and product videos [here](https://potensio.zendesk.com/). Disclosure - I am part and lead of Potens.io Team (also stated in my SO Profile)

Comment: How many row do you have?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere A little bit above 2 million.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigQuery can't call external API. So you can't use Translation API directly from BigQuery.

My idea is the following

- Create a new Google Sheet with a connected sheet to BigQuery
- Get all the data of the table in Google Sheet
- Use Google Sheet translation capacity ([GOOGLETRANSLATE function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093331))
- Create a [federated table in BigQuery to read in your Google Sheet](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive)

Sadly, I can't test the connected sheet feature because it's reserved to paid user, and I no longer have a paid corporate account (I switched company 1 month ago). I can't validate this solution end to end and help you further.